# Configure kafka-net to stop sending latest messages

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using kafka 0.8.1.1 on a Red Hat VM with kafka-net plugin. How can I configure my consumer to stop receiving earlier messages from kafka?

My consumer code:

```
var options = new KafkaOptions(new Uri("tcp://199.53.249.150:9092"), new Uri("tcp://199.53.249.151:9092"));

Stopwatch sp = new Stopwatch();
var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions("Test", router));

ThreadStart start2 = () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        sp.Start();
        foreach (var message in consumer.Consume())
        {
            if (MessageDecoderReceiver.MessageBase(message.Value) != null)
            {
                PrintMessage(MessageDecoderReceiver.MessageBase(message.Value).ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message.Value);
            }
        }
        sp.Stop();
    }
};
var thread2 = new Thread(start2);
thread2.Start();
```

Comment: I added a tag for the language you appear to be using and tweaked the body and title for better readability. I also [removed a tag from the title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Consumer in Kafka-net does not currently auto track the offsets being consumed.  You will have to implement the offset tracking manually.

To Store the offset in kafka version 0.8.1:

```
 var commit = new OffsetCommitRequest
            {
                ConsumerGroup = consumerGroup,
                OffsetCommits = new List<OffsetCommit>
                            {
                                new OffsetCommit
                                    {
                                        PartitionId = partitionId,
                                        Topic = IntegrationConfig.IntegrationTopic,
                                        Offset = offset,
                                        Metadata = metadata
                                    }
                            }
            };

var commitResponse = conn.Connection.SendAsync(commit).Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

To set the consumer to start importing at a specific offset point:

```
var offsets = consumer.GetTopicOffsetAsync(IntegrationConfig.IntegrationTopic).Result
                    .Select(x => new OffsetPosition(x.PartitionId, x.Offsets.Max())).ToArray();

var consumer = new Consumer(new ConsumerOptions(IntegrationConfig.IntegrationTopic, router), offsets);
```

Note the above code will set the consumer to start consuming at the very end of the log, effectively only receiving new messages.

Comment: Could you shed some light on how to consume the offset that you have committed? Getting the client's GetTopicOffsetAsync does not return the committed offsets. It only returns 2 values: 0 (presumably the first) and the last offset.

Also, for other readers, you can get the connection using the KafkaOptions' KafkaConnectionFactory method:
`_options.KafkaConnectionFactory.Create(uri, _options.ResponseTimeoutMs, _options.Log)`

Comment: Nvm I dug through the source and found the OffsetFetchRequest\Response class. So it looks like we need to get all the partitions using your GetTopicOffset and then fetch the stored offset for each of the partitions using the OffsetFetchRequest, whose response is then passed into the consumer in it's ConsumerOptions.

Comment: @arviman have you tried sending fetching the offset and setting it afterwards?  I've tried but any subsequent consumption just blocks and returns no entries.

Comment: @Slugart - yes it works. If you mean, setting the offset midway during a consumption, the answer is "no". If you pass in offsets into ConsumerOptions before consuming, it works. 
BTW - Are you consuming a topic with multiple partitions? I found that jRoland's kafka-net driver has a bug that forgets to hydrate partitionId's.  (it only hydrates offsetIds and defaults partitionId to 0). I used the driver "misakai-kafka" to solve that problem.

Comment: @arviman I'm setting the offset before the consumption starts and the topic has a single partition.  In the end I had to create two BrokerRouters, one to set the offset and another to consume.  Is still don't know why though.

Comment: @Slugart - Strange. It worked fine with just one for me. Anyway, whatever works!

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering though, why can't I specify for which consumer group to retrieve the offsets? How would I go about doing that?